How to get attachment thumbnail of workitem in Azure DevOps API?
I need to preview all the attachments of a workitem in compressed size (thumbnail)
I don't want to download full-size attachments.
I know currently we need to use following link
$url = https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/434?**$expand=all**&api-version=5.0
and loop and get each attachment by id.
but its downloads in full size.
Do we have any way to see compressed attachment preview first before download ?

Update
Per the Get attachment REST API of Azure DevOps, it only gets the full contents from the WIT attachment files and doesn't support generating any compressed size thumbnail.
For the text contents, you may preview the information in the script as what is done like below without saving those contents into any new file.
For other contents type like images, the API itself doesn't generate a compressed size thumbnail.

Based on your requirement, I managed to preview the contents of the sample attachment files of a work item with the attament.url.

Here is a sample script for your refence.
$organization = "AzureDevOpsOrgName"
$project = "TheProjectName"
$witId = "2175"
$MyPat = "xxxxxx"
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'basic ' + "$B64Pat"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}
$witURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($witId)?`$expand=all&api-version=7.2-preview.3"
$wit = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $witURL -Headers $headers

$attachments = $wit.relations | Where-Object { $_.rel -eq 'AttachedFile' }
foreach ($attachment in $attachments) {
    Write-Host PREVIEW - $attachment.attributes.name:
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $attachment.url -Headers $headers
}



But this will download full size attachment, anyway to just download preview?

Hi @Ragul, during my test with the above script on my local machine, I didn't observe it download any attachment files anywhere. May I know in which path you could see the files were downloaded and are you sure we are using the same URL or script? Thx.

yes, I am using the same URL, when I use $attachment.url size is the same as the actual file size.

The API will get the contents of an attachment file indeed, but will not generate any downloaded file. Have you run any script output the contents as a file? Can you please share the part of script you deal with the response got by $attachment.url?

Thanks again for your help, Yes it's getting the content of the attachment in full size, But actually I need a thumbline view of the attachment. If my attmentent image size is 4 mb I just need thumbline of that image like 50kb size. end user will see the preview and select a file to display full size image.

Yes, I can understand your requirement. So I think what you need is to firstly use API to get the full contents and then process the contents to generate a thumbnail image, right? As far as we know, for the ADO REST API itself doesn't support generate thumbnail. I am more familiar with Azure DevOps, but I am afraid that I don't know much on how to process the contents to generate a thumbnail and it seemed a general query irrelevant to Azure DevOps. Have you reached out to other subcommunities about the the second part?
